# SonarQube vulnerability: Explicitly declare the visibility for variable

Tags: java, variables, sonarqube, access-modifiers

As well known in Java present default visibility modifier. As I understand this modifier can be used like other modifiers. But why SonarQube mark default modifier as vulnerability - Explicitly declare the visibility for "var"?

Comment: This is special rule in your "quality profile". You may set any rules you want.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the description of [the rule](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2039).

> Failing to explicitly declare the visibility of a member variable
>   could result it in having a visibility you don't expect, and
>   potentially leave it open to unexpected modification by other classes.

If you have a property of a class package private then any class in the same package can modify this property.

But Package private still has valid uses. For example you might want to declare a class as package private so that it can be used inside the package it is declared in but remains hidden from public use.

Comment: I have a package-private static variable which uses by all classes in the package. When I specified this variable as protected (for sonarqube) the vulnerability disappeared. But protected variable is more vulnerable than package-private. Or not? Even my ide (Intellij IDEA) says to change modificator to package-private.

Comment: It depends. Is static variable optimal for the sharing of such information? If you think it is you can just mark it as false positive.